# How to resolve import error in visual studio code in window 8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, error-handling

When I try to import pygame in visual studio code, it shows me error

The following error is shown by visual studio code:

`mod= importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)`

> Import error :DLL load failed while importing pywintypes : the
> specified procedures could not be found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For windows, if you need to upgrade pip

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Install pypywin32 package

```
python -m pip install pypiwin32
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
pip3 install pypiwin32
```

Pywintypes is part of the Python for Windows extensions, otherwise known as pywin32. You'll need to install that to get access to Pywintypes.